# foreachを使用して配列を作成したい

Tags: php, fuelphp

データのリストを作成しています。
既に配列の型のデータがあるのですが、データの足し引きをする関係で一度foreachに入れています。
foreach処理の最後に$a_listという変数に改めて配列を入れなおしたいのですが、 `Error - Unsupported operand types~`というエラーがでます。

```
$a_list[] =array();
 $arrays=Array (     
　[0] => Array         (             [z] => 12             [x] => 24         )      
　[1] => Array         (             [z] => 13             [x] => 25         )      
　[2] => Array         (             [z] => 14             [x] => 26         )  
);
foreach($arrays as $array){
    $a_list[] += array($array);
}
```

理想とする期待結果

```
$a_list=Array (     
　[0] => Array         (             [z] => 12             [x] => 24         )      
　[1] => Array         (             [z] => 13             [x] => 25         )      
　[2] => Array         (             [z] => 14             [x] => 26         )  
);
```

エラー内容を調べたところどちらかが配列と認識されていないケースがあるという記載を見つけましたが、debugして確認するとどちらも配列の形をしています。
何か解消法ありましたらご教授ください。

Comment: 記載されているのは dump image になっているので詳しい事は分かりませんが、`$a_list[] =array();` は `$a_list = array();` で、`$a_list[] += array($array);` は `$a_list[] = $array;` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: その通りの実行で期待結果得られました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_list[] =array();を$a_list = array();
に変更、
$a_list[] += array($array);を$a_list[] = array($array);
に変更で期待結果が得られました。
foreachの中で初めての呼び出しであっても+=を使用しないので、事前の宣言が不要なため、$a_list = array();は記載がなくとも問題ありませんでした。